# iOS: Retrieving an entire YouTube playlist (all videos) with YouTube Gdata API

Tags: ios, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I have managed to use the GData in iPhone project.
I have also managed to get all the Uploads videos and all the playlist name also.

Reference to the project: [YouTubeList](https://github.com/naorcho/YouTubeUploadsList)

I need to get all the link of the playlist in order to show the video when a cell is pressed (you can see how it works in the project I add)

Here is some code which with it I get the playlist names:

```
    // get the youtube service
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    // feed id for user playlist
    NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDPlaylists;
    // construct the feed url
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser
                                                         userFeedID:uploadsID];
    // make API call
    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed
          error:(NSError *)error {

    self.feed = (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;
    NSLog(@"FEED:%@", [self.feed entries]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The code above bring a list of all playlist I have in the account.
I need to get the videos of a specific playlist

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the IDE, the question is ***not*** about Xcode.

Comment: OK, I'll remove the Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with the following:

In the viewDidLoad

```
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PlayList_ID"];
// make API call

[service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                    delegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector(playlistTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

Then, the method:

```
- (void)playlistTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedYouTubePlaylist *)feed error:(NSError *)error {
  if(!error)
   {
       // save the feed and reload the table
       self.feed = feed;
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
}
```